# how to enable ffmpeg enable in server

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, ffmpeg

The server seems to not support ffmpeg format while I asked the support team but I am confused why this happens with the server as the ffmpeg is widely used for processing videos & audio format files in the server side.

Is there any way do something from my part to make this working.

Comment: Can you give more info. Is this Linux or Widows server? Shared or dedicated?

Answer (score 0):

Basically no, it's an application external to PHP. Either it is installed (by the server administrator) or it is not. In the latter case: either you're very good at begging and cajoling, or you go in search of a server that offers it.

If you can't find one, I'm happy with [Dathorn](http://ww.dathorn.com).

Comment: thanks for your comments, I will find a way to solve this issue by getting another hosting account